# make regex match to the next instance not the last

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have the below group of text and want to extract the bold text:

24.SSRTKNEWSHK1HNLYVR1865U30AUG-  4.1 .8387254346122C2
 25.SSRTKNEWSHK1YVRHNL1864J22AUG-  5.1 .8387254346123C1
 **1.1YEUNG/LAWRENCE.KWANLEUNG*JWA**  **2.1YEUNG/LILY.LIMKUO*JWA**
 **3.1YEUNG/ANDREA.LAUREN*JWA**  **4.1YEUNG/ETHAN.WESLEY*JWA**
 **5.1YEUNG/WINSTON.JEREMY*JWA**
 1 WS1864J 22AUG TH YVRHNL HK5   600P  904P/O $ E
 2 WS1865U 30AUG FR HNLYVR HK5  1010P  656A#1/O $ E

I want to use Javascript to end up with is an array like this:

```
[0] ->  1.1YEUNG/LAWRENCE.KWANLEUNG*JWA  
[1] ->  2.1YEUNG/LILY.LIMKUO*JWA
[2] ->  3.1YEUNG/ANDREA.LAUREN*JWA  
[3] ->  4.1YEUNG/ETHAN.WESLEY*JWA
[4] ->  5.1YEUNG/WINSTON.JEREMY*JWA
```

What ive come up with so far is: `/[\d]{1}\.[\d]{1}.+\*[A-Z]{3}/`

This matches the text but any matches found on the same line are treated as one match so I end up with:

```
[0] ->  1.1YEUNG/LAWRENCE.KWANLEUNG*JWA 2.1YEUNG/LILY.LIMKUO*JWA
[1] ->  3.1YEUNG/ANDREA.LAUREN*JWA 4.1YEUNG/ETHAN.WESLEY*JWA    
[2] ->  5.1YEUNG/WINSTON.JEREMY*JWA
```

How can I tell this regex to only match to the next intance of `\*[A-Z]{3}` rather than the last?

Im working on this in RegexBuddy so there's no real javascript to show but here is the if statement it generates on the "use" page:

```
if (subject.match(/[\d]{1}\.[\d]{1}.+\*[A-Z]{3}/)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: try `.+?` instead of `.+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern is greedy, the `.+` grabs *everything* that is can and the pattern still match.

This pattern works:

```
\d\.\d[A-Za-z].+?\*[A-Z]{3}
```

I have made the `.+` lazy by adding a `.+?`, this means that it matches the *minimum* number of characters that it can and the pattern still match.

Note that `[\d]{1}` is the same as `\d{1}` which is the same as `\d`. I have also forced the character after the second digit to be a `[A-Za-z]` as otherwise everything from the first `4.1` will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = [
    "24.SSRTKNEWSHK1HNLYVR1865U30AUG- 4.1 .8387254346122C2",
    "25.SSRTKNEWSHK1YVRHNL1864J22AUG- 5.1 .8387254346123C1",
    "1.1YEUNG/LAWRENCE.KWANLEUNG*JWA 2.1YEUNG/LILY.LIMKUO*JWA",
    "3.1YEUNG/ANDREA.LAUREN*JWA 4.1YEUNG/ETHAN.WESLEY*JWA",
    "5.1YEUNG/WINSTON.JEREMY*JWA 1 WS1864J 22AUG TH YVRHNL HK5 600P",
    "904P/O $ E 2 WS1865U 30AUG FR HNLYVR HK5 1010P 656A#1/O $ E"].join("\n");
text.match(/\d\.\d[a-z\/.*]+/igm);
```

But I don't know what exactly your criteria is, so if this doesn't do what you want, you'd need to explain it better.